# TestNG cannot find test methods with inheritance

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, testng

Edit: I solved this problem by switching to JUnit. I did not change much other than switching the code to the JUnit equivalent and switching `useTestNG()` to `useJUnit()`

This may be a gradle and/or Intellij problem

Whenever I run the TestNG tests below in Intellij using gradle, I get the error message.

> No tests found for given includes: com.github.myrepo.ProjectName

The following are my test files

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public abstract class AbstractFoo {

   public abstract void abstractMethod();

    @Test
    final void passingTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

```
public class Foo extends AbstractFoo{
    @Override
    public void abstractMethod() {
        System.out.println("Implementation");
    }
}
```

This error only occurs if i have the "Run tests using" option set to gradle. If I switch the option to Intellij and add the JVM argument `-Dtestng.dtd.http=true`, it works.

My build.gradle.kts file

```
plugins {
    java
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains", "annotations", "20.1.0")
    implementation("org.apache.commons", "commons-lang3", "3.11")


    testImplementation("org.testng", "testng", "7.3.0")
    testImplementation("org.mockito", "mockito-core", "3.5.13")
}

tasks {
    test {
        useTestNG()
    }
}
```

Comment: try to Invalidate Caches. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: @zabaykal Does not do anything